# How to capture mouse/touch events in TeeChart for Android?

Tags: java, android, mouseevent, teechart

My goal is to be able to have the user select a range of data for processing on a line or area chart in Steema's TeeChart for Android(Java).  I found a couple clues online about disabling zoom and 3d, but I can't find a way to access all of the mouse(or touch) events.  See http://www.teechart.net/support/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=12357 for a very related question.  Unfortunately, it's answered in what looks like Basic.  Those methods are marked "internal" in the Java version and I can't access them.
The only success with accessible methods I've had is with .addChartMouseListener and overriding backgroundClicked.  That seems to be called on a mouse down type event and not with mouse motion or mouse up.  To accomplish the same kind of thing in the provided link, it looks like I need to find a way to access "MouseMove" and "MouseUp".  TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid the "MouseMove", "MouseUp" and "MouseUp" events can't be accessed in TeeChart Java for Android yet. I've added to the wish list to implement them in future releases.

Yeray Alonso

Steema Support Central

Answer (score 0):

TeeChart had one listener for mouseclick , you can add it using addChartMouseListener(new ChartMouseListener())